# Create node to receive data from OXTS imu

Tags: ros, ethernet

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have an OXTS box basically a imu + gps. I have connected it through Ethernet port.

I'm fairly new to ROS and don't know how to create a UDP socket in ros to receive the data i.e the UDP broadcast from the OXTS.

Could someone please suggest where I should start?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/230042/create-node-to-receive-data-from-oxts-imu/) by [b-sriram](https://answers.ros.org/users/26278/b-sriram/) on ROS Answers with karma: 105 on 2016-03-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-03-24**:
If the device is capable of outputting NMEA messages, you might be able to use any of the available NMEA compatible drivers (such as [ros-drivers/nmea_navsat_driver](https://github.com/ros-drivers/nmea_navsat_driver)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This following driver might work for you.
http://wiki.ros.org/oxford_gps_eth
https://bitbucket.org/DataspeedInc/oxford_gps_eth

---

Originally posted by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) with karma: 1416 on 2016-03-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [b-sriram](https://answers.ros.org/users/26278/b-sriram/) on 2016-03-24**:
thanks a lot

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-03-06**:
@b-sriram Hi, have you solved the problem? I tried this but it doesnt publish anything...

**Comment by [b-sriram](https://answers.ros.org/users/26278/b-sriram/) on 2017-03-06**:
Ya the problem was solved. Did you get any message like connected to RT3003v2 on the terminal when you run the node?

PS: First and foremost the OXTS has to be initialised

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-03-06**:
yeah I got like "connected to  at port (3000)". I checked the official website and it says initialize by speed > 5m/s. Have you done this? I cannt believe it because normally GPS can publish data whenever state it is...

**Comment by [b-sriram](https://answers.ros.org/users/26278/b-sriram/) on 2017-03-06**:
Its true if you use the GUI provided with OXTS. But to get NCOM packets it has to be initialised. Once initialised the node starts to publish all the data

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-03-06**:
Thank you very much! I will try that.@b-sriram

**Comment by [Bill5785](https://answers.ros.org/users/29209/bill5785/) on 2017-03-06**:
@b-sriram just want to make sure. Once initialized, do I need to always keep the speed > 5? If so, this doesnt make sense to me...

**Comment by [b-sriram](https://answers.ros.org/users/26278/b-sriram/) on 2017-03-07**:
Initializing once is enough. Then you'd be getting continuous output from the sensors

**Comment by [msy](https://answers.ros.org/users/36305/msy/) on 2018-07-06**:
Hi @b-sriram, I met the same problem with @Bill5785. And I drove the car in a speed more than 10 m/s for at least 10 minutes. But I still can't get any message published from the topics. Did I miss anything? Thank you in advance for your help.

**Comment by [b-sriram](https://answers.ros.org/users/26278/b-sriram/) on 2018-07-12**:
Hi @msy is your Ethernet port configured properly? Are you on the same subnet as the OXTS?

**Comment by [839977837wgj](https://answers.ros.org/users/41713/839977837wgj/) on 2019-05-22**:
I have similar questions. Did RT Range or RT 3000v1 work well with this driver. I see the driver is only tested with RT3000v2. Thank you for your reply in advance

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-22**:
@839977837wgj: do not post answers to ask a follow-up/related question. A comment is ok, but perhaps a new question might be better.